# Monotonically of symmetric positive definite matrix divided by its smallest eigenvalue

Tags: matrices

Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be two symmetric positive definite matrices satisfying $P_1 \succ P_2$. Denote $\lambda_{min}(P_1)$ and $\lambda_{min}(P_2)$ as their smallest eigenvalues. Can we prove the following inequality:

$\frac{P_1}{\lambda_{min}(P_1)} \succ \frac{P_2}{\lambda_{min}(P_2)}$

Thanks for any comment and hint!

Comment: Not strictly. Take $P_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0\\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $P_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Then $P_1 / \lambda_{min} (P_1) = P_2 / \lambda_{min} (P_2)$.

Comment: Thanks Leo. Sometimes the inequality may even hold on the other way around, i.e. $\succ$ becomes $\prec$.